# Find difference between list of dates in python

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I want to find difference between list of dates in days.

I have a list of Timestamp object.

```
[Timestamp('2016-10-18 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2016-10-18 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2016-10-19 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2016-10-29 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2016-10-31 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2016-11-01 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2016-11-09 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2016-11-09 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2016-11-11 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2016-11-13 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2016-11-13 00:00:00')]
```

And I want the following result

```
[0,1,10,2,1,8,0,2,2,0]
```

I tried the following code but I am getting compilation error "TypeError: 'Timestamp' object is not iterable"

```
def calculateInterOrderTime(dateList):
   result = map(lambda x: [i / np.timedelta64(1, 'D') for i in np.diff([c for c in x])[0]],dateList)
   print(list(result))
```

It will be great if someone can help me with my lambda expression to do what I want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `Series` constructor, [`Series.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html), [`Series.dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html), remove first value by [`Series.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iloc.html), convert to integers and then to lists:

```
print (pd.Series(dateList).diff().dt.days.iloc[1:].astype(int).tolist())
[0, 1, 10, 2, 1, 8, 0, 2, 2, 0]
```

Your solution should be changed with `DatetimeIndex`, so is possible divide all values without list comprehension:

```
print ((np.diff(pd.DatetimeIndex(dateList)) / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')).astype(int).tolist())
[0, 1, 10, 2, 1, 8, 0, 2, 2, 0]
```

Answer (score 6):

Since that is `list` we can using list operation

```
[(t - s).days for s, t in zip(l, l[1:])]
Out[137]: [0, 1, 10, 2, 1, 8, 0, 2, 2, 0]
```

Comment: no Pandas. Excellent.

Answer (score 3):

Since pandas is tagged where `l` is your list , you can use: [`series.diff()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html):

```
pd.Series(l).diff().dt.days.dropna().tolist()
```

---

```
[0.0, 1.0, 10.0, 2.0, 1.0, 8.0, 0.0, 2.0, 2.0, 0.0]
```